# Google Images either cranks CPU or does not open images

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cpu, images

For a couple of days now, I have come across an interesting problem yet extremely annoying:

**Google Images stopped working properly on my computer.**

Under Chrome:

- the page will load, clicking an image will show it although it will take a couple of seconds
- clearing browser data will *eventually* fix it up but only for a short time
- removing all extensions and even re-installing Chrome doesn't help
- in Incognito mode it is the same
- disconnecting Google account does not change the situation

Under Firefox and Edge:

- the page will load normally but then nothing happens when I click an image
- clearing browsing data does not do anything

After a little inspection, I can see that hundreds of the following error are happening every few seconds (on every browser):

[image]

I've even tried to switch to another Windows account (to assert that it was unrelated) but unfortunately it's not.

**Did anyone ever experience such issue and is there a fix for it ?**

Here are my computer specs for reference:

> Windows 10
>
> Intel Intel Core i7 4770 @ 3.40GHz
>
> 16.0GB DDR3
>
> 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series
>
> 238GB Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series

Comment: im experiencing the same thing, noticed as of today. resorting to using ddg as a temporary solution

Comment: That's really weird, it reminds me of the bug that was resetting default apps on each reboot then vanished by itself ...

Comment: @shadesofdarkred guess what, it just fixed itself at the end of the day !

Comment: i guess google caught onto that eventually